# Cosmic expansion from De-Sitter global coordinates metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, de-sitter-spacetime

Can we show cosmic expansion from this dS metric?
\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = -d\tau^{2} + R^{2}\cosh^{2}(\tau/R) d\Omega^{2}_{3}
\end{equation}

I understand that in this background, matter can be set to zero. But can we have something exhibiting the equivalent of the FLRW Friedmann equation,
\begin{equation}
H^{2} = \frac{\rho}{3}+\frac{\Lambda}{3}-\frac{K}{a^{2}}, \quad \rightarrow H^{2} =\frac{\Lambda}{3}-\frac{K}{a^{2}}, \quad \text{for} \quad \rho=0
\end{equation}
but starting from the above dS metric in global coordinates? Is there even a point in doing that or one can infer dS expansion just by setting $\rho=0$ and noting that the expansion factor $a(t)=\cosh^{2}(\tau/R)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{d}\Omega_3^2$ is a $3$-sphere, which is homogeneous and isotropic. Hence, the metric you're exhibiting *is* a FLRW solution with $a(\tau) = R \cosh\left(\frac{\tau}{R}\right)$, hence it does solve the Friedmann equations (if we're assuming General Relativity to hold). There's nothing new to be derived.

Comment: Makes perfect sense... Thanks